# How do I force setup.py to include the `__init__.py` file and make my package importable?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, pypi

I am trying to make my Python [project](https://github.com/hq6/smux/blob/master/setup.py) importable by people who install it using `pip`. Although it contains a `__init__.py` and works as a package locally, it seems that I am misunderstanding how setuptools works.

I run the following three commands to upload the package.

```
python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
python3 -m pip install  --upgrade twine
python3 -m twine upload dist/*
```

Then on a different machine, I run `pip3 install smux.py`. The result is that I can access `smux.py` as a command, but I get an import error when trying to import it.

```
python3
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import smux
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'smux'
```

After running the `setup.py` commands above, I examined `smux.py.egg-info/SOURCES.txt` in the current directory and find it contains the following:

```
README.md
setup.py
smux.py
smux.py.egg-info/PKG-INFO
smux.py.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
smux.py.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
smux.py.egg-info/top_level.txt
```

The file `__init__.py` is missing.

**How do I either get that file into the package, or modify the setup call to make `smux` importable?**

Comment: This doesn't look like a package. It doesn't look like it ever should have been a package, and it doesn't look like it needs to be a package. Why do you want it to be a package? How are you attempting to import it?

Comment: It's a command line tool and also a one-function API that can be used by other scripts for generating lists of commands to run in different tmux windows. It's clunky for other scripts to generate an smux file and then use `os.system` to run `smux.py`.

Comment: I'm trying to import it with `import smux`. 
This works locally when I am in the parent directory where I clone the project. 
It just does not work after it has been packaged, uploaded, and re-downloaded.

Comment: Looking at your repository, `create` is a function, so the import would just be `import smux`, not `import smux.create`, and you don't need a package for that. (Also, you should really include a [mcve] in your question. The setup.py in particular contains crucial information, and your repository doesn't even have an `__init__.py` in the first place, contrary to the question body.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I have pushed now. Apologies for not creating an MWE, but I don't know how to do that without posting credentials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `setup` call looks like this:

```
setup(
  name="smux.py",
  version='0.1.1',
  scripts=['smux.py'],
  author="Henry Qin",
  author_email="root@hq6.me",
  description="Simple tmux launcher that will take less than 2 minutes to learn and should work across all versions of tmux",
  long_description=long_description,
  platforms=["All platforms that tmux runs on."],
  license="MIT",
  url="https://github.com/hq6/smux"
)
```

With the `scripts` argument, you've told setuptools that `smux.py` is a script, not a module. Accordingly, it gets installed as a script, not a module.

Your code does not need an `__init__.py` and should not have one. Having an `__init__.py` will not help. You need to tell setuptools to install your file as a module rather than a script, and register an entry point separately, with a [`console_scripts`](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#console-scripts) entry in the `entry_points` argument:

```
setup(
    ...
    # no scripts= line
    py_modules=['smux'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['smux=smux:main']
    }
)
```

Then when your code is installed, `smux` will be importable, and there will be a `smux` script available from the command line that calls `smux.main`.

Comment: Just tried this, although I wanted the script to be named `smux.py` instead of `smux` for backward compatibility reasons, so I tried `smux.py=` instead of `smux=`.

Comment: Now imports work but the command no longer works, so I suspect it's no longer installing in a well-known path like `/usr/bin/local`.

Comment: I just tried with `smux=smux:main` and that also did not produce a script called `smux` on my PATH, or anywhere I could find. These are `0.1.3` and `0.1.4` on Pypi respectively.

Comment: @merlin2011: Whoops, mixed up the syntax - `console_scripts` doesn't work like I had it in the initial version of my answer. Edited.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like this works iff the generated script is not named `smux.py`, because this causes a circular dependency resulting in `ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from partially initialized module 'smux' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/local/bin/smux.py) `

Comment: I cannot change the external name of the script without breaking scripts that other people have written that wrap it, and changing the module name is going to be confusing, so I guess I need to find a different solution to work around this. :(

Comment: I think you've technically answered the question as written though. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is the more kosher and modern one, and I would use that and name the script `smux` if I did not have legacy scripts depending on the name `smux.py`. Unfortunately, others have wrapped `smux.py` and it would be unkind to break their scripts.

Here is what I did to avoid the circular dependency problem that arises from having a legacy script name that ends in `.py` and conflicts with the module naming.

I ended up modifying the `setup` call to have both of the following.

```
  py_modules=['smux'],
  scripts=['smux.py']
```

My experiments demonstrate that this has the desired effect of making the module importable while preserving a working script under the name `smux.py`.